# showing exception already handled for some unhandled checked exception

Tags: java

In the code block below `meth2()` throws `ExcepOne` and `ExcepTwo`, custom exceptions, that extend `Exception`, so they are checked. But when I happen to write another catch block for `IOException`, I am getting a compilation error saying that `IOException` has already been caught. Why is it showing that? And where is it getting caught?

```
 public class ExceptionConcepts {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExcepOne{

    System.out.println("In main method");
    try{
    meth1();
    }catch(ExcepOne e1)
    {
        System.out.println("Finally caught ExcepOne");
    }
}
public static void meth1() throws ExcepOne{
   try{
    meth2();
   }catch(ExcepTwo e2)
   {
       System.out.println("In meth1 catch for Exceptwo");
       throw new ExcepOne("1ond");
   }

    catch(ExcepOne e1)
   {
       System.out.println("In meth1 catch for ExcepOne");
   }
    catch(IOException ie) // I get a compilation error here
     {

     }
 }
public static void meth2() throws ExcepOne,ExcepTwo{


  int i=-1;
  try{
  if(i<0)
      throw new ExcepOne("one");
   else
      throw new ExcepTwo("two");
  }

  catch(ExcepTwo e1)
  {
      System.out.println("in catch of ExcepTwo");
      throw new ExcepTwo("2");
  }
  catch(ExcepOne e2)
  {
      System.out.println("in catch of ExcepOne");
      throw new ExcepOne("1");
  }
  finally
  {
      System.out.println("I am finally");
      throw new ExcepTwo("2");
  }
 }
}

public class ExcepOne extends Exception()
{
public ExcepOne(String msg)
 {
 super(msg);
 }
} 
public class ExcepTwo extends Exception()
{
public ExcepTwo(String msg)
 {
super(msg);
 }
}
```

Comment: Post the code declaring `ExcepTwo` and `ExcepOne`. My guess is that one of them is actually an `IOException`.

Comment: Are you sure the error you have is not "Unreachable catch block for IOException."?

Comment: I posted that code of ExcepOne and ExcepTwo. Please check now. Thank you.

Comment: No, I rechecked it just now! it says"exception IOException has already been caught."

Comment: Then I guess you need to post a simplified version of `meth2`. I fail to see what could be wrong here (except that the exceptions you posted do not actually compile)

Comment: Parenthesis after `extends Exception` are a syntactic error.

Comment: I forgor to close the paranthesis of my exceptions, sorry about that. Now I corrected. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing :

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

When you add that to your source one of this two things will happen :
  - If the try block can throw `IOException` the program will compile.
  - Otherwise you will get the compilation `error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement`

Comment: Got it brother, Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. The error message was quite confusing and also puzzled me. If this solved your issue you might wish to accept the answer as explained here : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work